# Java - Reading A Binary File In Parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, random-access

I have a binary file that contains blocks of information (*I'll refer to them as packets henceforth*). Each packet consists of a fixed-length header and a variable length body. I've to determine the lenth of the body from the packet header itself. My task is to read these packets from the file and perform some operation on them. Currently I'm performing this task as follows:

- Opening the file as a random access file and going to a specific start position (a user-specified start position). Reading the 1st packet from this position. Performing the specific operation
- Then in a loop

  - reading the next packet
  - performing my operation
    This goes on till I hit the end of file marker.

As you can guess, when the file size is huge, reading each packet serially and processing it is a time-consuming affair. I want to somehow parallelize this operation i.e. packet generation operation and put it in some blocking queue and then parallely retrieve each packet from the queue and perform my operation.

Can someone suggest how may I generate these packets in parallel?

Comment: Does the position in the file of each packet header (after the first) depend on the size of the preceding packet?

Comment: @Ted: Not really. I detect the start of the next packet header based on a particular signature of the byte read. It would appear somewhere after the end of the preceding packet but not at any specific position as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only have one thread read in the file sequentially since I'm assuming the file lies in a single drive. Reading the file is limited by your IO speed so there's no point in parallelizing that in the CPU. In fact, reading non-sequentially will actually significantly decrease your performance since regular hard drives are designed for sequential IO. For each packet it reads in, it should put that object into a thread-safe queue.

Now you can start parallelizing the processing of the packets. Create multiple threads and have them each read in packets from the queue. Each thread should do their processing and put it into some "finished" queue.

Once the IO thread has finished reading in the file, a flag should be set so that the working threads stop once the queue is empty.

Comment: +1 though modern SSD may make parallel reads of a contiguous file still meaningfully faster than sequential reads.

Comment: @sarnold: That may be true. I don't have enough experience w/ SSD architectures to say anything about it though :P

Comment: +1 for discouraging the read to be made by multiple threads, this is very important for performance.

Comment: @tskuzzy: Thanks for the suggestions. I guess processing the packets in parallel would be the best step forward!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a disk with platters (i.e. not an SSD) then there is no point having more than one thread read the file since all you will do is thrash the disk causing the disk arm to introduce millisecond delays.  If you have an SSD its a different story and you could parallelise the reading.

Instead you should have one thread reading the data from the file and creating the packets, then doing the following:

- wait on a shared semaphore 'A' (which has been initialised to some number that will be your 'max buffered packets' count)
- lock a shared object
- append the packet to a LinkedList
- signal another shared semaphore 'B' (this one is tracking the count of the packets in the buffer)

Then you can have many other threads doing the following:

- wait on the 'B' semaphore (to ensure there is a packet to be processed)
- lock the shared object
- do getFirst() on the LinkedList and store the packet in a local variable
- signal semaphore 'A' to allow another packet into the buffered packet list

This will ensure you are reading packets as fast as possible (from a platter disk) by striping them in one continuous sequence, and it will ensure that you are processing multiple packets at once without any polling.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyM for your suggestion! I guess both of you and the previous answer point in the same direction, i.e. processing the packets in parallel rather than accessing the file in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the known fast method is using java.nio.MappedByteBuffer

Comment: This sounds like a simple memory mapping. How does one use this to discover packets stored on non-standardized byte boundaries?

Comment: If the header has a length, you can at least skip packets - if not, you do a parallel scan and adjust! It's definitely a faster way to preload blocks into memory and scan them than use the file pointer and advance